# Java EE 6 - Why does an interceptor project need to be declared as ejb-jar and not simply a jar?

Tags: ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, cdi

I was able to determine what I needed to do to get my interceptor working; however, I don't understand why I had to do that.  All of the projects I am using my interceptor project in are either jar / war and CDI-enabled.

I thought CDI covered both EJB beans, regular POJO beans, properties, and anything resolveable via EL.  And ... that to register an interceptor for CDI beans, I could simply declare it in beans.xml.  None of my projects are EARs.

Now that I have it working by building the project as an ejb-jar, that is the main thing, but am I wrong in thinking it should work in beans.xml alone and building the project as just a regular jar?

Please point me to any documentation that specifies this clearly, everything on oracle's site indicates beans.xml should suffice.

Walter

Comment: Basically you still want an answer to your previous question? Not sure what docs you want, you only need beans.xml as per your own findings. 

I never use ejb and never had any issues whatsoever.

Comment: I actually think the problem I am having is a bug in Glassfish 3.x and will be resolved in 4.x whenever that will be.